# Bash How to remove or filter arguments with values?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a BASH script that calls another script or command as a wrapper. Calling arguments should be collect passed with one exception. How to filter a special argument name value pair?

Like for example when i call the first script with argument count `X=$#`:

```
$ ./foo.sh -v --first val1 ... --argname 'value with spaces' ... --last val3
```

It should then call a second command or script with new argument count `X'=X-2` :

```
$ ./bar.sh -v --first val1 ... --last val3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this **solution** for `foo.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "executing foo.sh:"

function arg_remove ()
{
    local array=("${@:3}")

    for ((i=0; i<"${#array[@]}"; ++i)); do
        case ${array[i]} in
            "$2") unset array[i]; unset array[i+1]; break ;;
        esac
    done

    # clean up unset array indexes
    for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
        new_array+=( "${array[i]}" )
    done
    array=("${new_array[@]}")
    unset new_array

    # assign array outside function scope
    local -g "$1=(  )"
    eval ${1}='("${array[@]}")'
}

echo "arguments income :" "$@"
arg_remove ARG_PASS '--argname' "$@"
echo "arguments passed :" "${ARG_PASS[@]}"

./bar.sh "${ARG_PASS[@]}"
```

The second **output test script** will only print all passed arguments grouped line by line `bar.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "executing bar.sh:"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
    key="$1"

    if [[ "$key" == --* ]]; then
        shift
        echo $key $1
    else
        echo $key
    fi
    shift
done
```

Now calling the first script **results** in:

```
$ ./foo.sh -v --first val1 --argname 'value with spaces' --last val3
executing foo.sh:
arguments income : -v --first val1 --argname value with spaces --last val3
arguments passed : -v --first val1 --last val3

executing bar.sh:
-v
--first val1
--last val3
```

You can also simplify the code and remove the separation of `function arg_remove` and clean up so you get a **minimalistic version** of `foo_mini.sh` without the need for `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("${@}")
filter="--argname"

for ((i=0; i<"${#args[@]}"; ++i)); do
    case ${args[i]} in
        "$filter") unset args[i]; unset args[i+1]; break ;;
    esac
done

./bar.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: the last line is passing only one argument

Comment: The code in this answer is *not* corrected, it still passes a single argument to `bar.sh`. Why is this only processing `"${@:3}"` and why are you copying the array instead of just modifying it in place? ... Though none of that makes a difference if you don't use the array when passing on the result.

Comment: @tripleee thank you, now the example is completed and tested

Comment: I'll still caution against using `eval` for anything unless you know *exactly* what you are passing in to it.

Answer (score 9):

There could be reasons you want the removal to happen in a function, but your attempt seems excessively complex as well as insecure and opaque in that it doesn't just filter an array.

```
args=("$@")
for ((i=0; i<"${#args[@]}"; ++i)); do
    case ${args[i]} in
        --argname) unset args[i]; unset args[i+1]; break;;
    esac
done
./bar.sh "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: this showed easy way to parse for extra arguments after a `--`  `for ((d=1; d<$#; ++d)); do; [[ ${!d} == "--" ]] && break; done; extraargs=("${@:$d+1:$#}") `

Comment: Or just add `--) break;;` to the existing `case` statement.